# generic technique to build LTL/CTL formula that satisfy specific inputs to a model

Tags: automata, logic, simulation, model-checking, linear-temporal-logic

I have an automaton, for example the below automaton and would like to generate a single formula (LTL or CTL, or some other representation) that satisfy exactly the traces provided. e.g.,

$t_1 = i^*f_4f_5f_7f_8f_7f_5f_4i^+$

$t_2 = i^*f_4f_6f_7f_9f_7f_6f_4i^+$

$t_3 = t_1^*t_2^*t_1^*$

$T = \{t_1 ...t_x\}$

I may have the notation wrong here, what I am trying to express is that any combination of $t_1$ and $t_2$ is acceptable, so long as `INIT` is visited between each. There could be any number of $t_x$, but they will all be known.

for example the traces

$i^*f_4f_5f_7f_9f_7f_5f_4i^+ \not\in T$ and

$i^*f_4f_5f_7f_8f_7f_5f_4f_5f_7f_8f_7f_5f_4i^+ \not\in T$ and

$i^*f_4(f_5f_7)^+ \not\in T$

Is there a technique of building a single formula(LTL, CTL, etc) $\psi$ such that $t \models \psi \iff t \in T$

[image]

Comment: First of all, it is not clear what a CTL formula would correspond to, since CTL is interpreted over trees (or structures), and not over words. Of course words are also trees, but I assume this isn't what you mean. In addition, automata are more expressive that both LTL and CTL, and therefore there may not be a corresponding formula at all. If, however, your automaton is Alternating-Weak with only self loops (AWW[1]), than it can be converted to LTL, using some form of "reverse engineering" on the translation from LTL to AWW[1].

Comment: @Shaull In all honesty I'm not sure if what I'm asking is possible or even practical. It's likely that I could express each trace as a regular expression, it is possible that a trace could contain a loop within itself (though not in the example given). What I was hoping for was a better way of checking an unknown trace than to directly compare to each of the known traces.

Comment: Check the proof for LTL/CTL being equivalent to the resp. automata models. Use the construction you find there. That said, I think asking about the real problem you are trying to solve may be more helpful.

Comment: @Raphael, this is pretty close to the real problem - I have a call graph for a program that represents every call allowed (F4-F9 could be considered functions) specific sequences of function calls are allowed (discovered via a test suite) after each execution of the program I want to check to see if a new, unexpected trace was discovered without having to check against every previous trace. I was hoping that a single formula could be used, that could (potentially) be modified as more traces are found.

Comment: So, you have no a-priori specification of the desired behaviour? I'm not sure what use formal methods will be to you if you feed them with test data only. That said, every single trace is a formula; just $\lor$ them.

Comment: @Raphael I was hoping to avoid just Ving them, as the size will be quite large (maybe 20k unique traces). The assumption is that the behaviour exposed by the test data is the only valid behaviour - within reason, e.g. a function that repeatedly calls another function can call it any number of times, but once it transitions to a different function, it can't then call the looped function without first going back to `INIT`.

My hope was to reduce multiple traces that have shared components to a smaller formula, e.g. $i^*f_4(f_5|f_6)f_7(f_8|f_9)f_7\$1i^+$, but that doesnt work.

Comment: These traces could potentially be very large, with lots of shared components. A trivial simplification of a trace could be
$i^*f_1f_1f_1....i^+$ to $i^*f_1^+i^+$

Comment: Since even minimization of regular expression is hard, I doubt minimizing $\omega$-regular expressions (which is what you seem to have there) will be any easier. But there *are* constructions from automaton to formlua; as I said, I'd look there.